# Is Flutter support the latest XCode 12.4 version?

Tags: android, frameworks, clang, simulator, xcode12

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...

Running Xcode build...
└─Compiling, linking and signing...                         2.4s
Xcode build done.                                           20.0s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
ld: framework not found Flutter
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.

Here is the error after i run using IOS Simulator, but it's ok if i use Android simulator..? Please explain .. ? help please thanks...

Comment: I have the same problem, I suppose that flutter at the moment doesn't support Xcode 12.4. The Android simulator will always work, as it doesn't need Xcode to build the project.

Comment: Any solutions found to this problem?